# Eliminate Hidden character (->) arrow in the TextBox

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, jakarta-ee

I am facing this weird issue for some time. I have a jsp page that has certain fields that need to be filled up and send further to get stored in the database.
There is one text box, to which I copy the data from Ms Word. The copied text looks good superficially however when I hover the mouse over the text, I see a  "->" character in that. This thing creates a mess while getting saved up in the database. This character is not acceptable at all.

A number of users use this application, and I really can not ask them not to use Ms Word for copying the data from.

Sample String- **32->some text->some text**
How can I strip the (->) character from the text?

I have searched the internet a lot but no luck.

Comment: Show us your codes please.

Comment: You can try String class' regular expression based methods to drop the needless characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you process the String in Java you can use the `String.replaceAll` method.

```
str=str.replaceAll("->"," ");
```

Comment: The most weird thing is that, it is hidden. It just shows up when I hover the mouse over the text. This trick does not work. I have tried it.

Comment: So, you should show how you get and process the text before you insert it in the database.